# What does :→ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

What does :→ mean?
and how is it differ from :→*W*?

So I know that :→ suffices T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v) and T(av)=a(Tv). Is it the same case for :→?

If possible, please show me the example.

Comment: $T : V \to W$ means $T$ a function, taking values from $V$, and producing values from $W$. Similarly, $T : V \to V$ means $T$ takes values from $V$ and produces values from $V$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Why are you answering in a comment?

Comment: @Arthur Because it's not a full answer, as it contains no examples. Before launching into a full, detailed answer to a question this fundamental, I often like to engage the asker in the comments (hopefully) to get a better grip on the specific cause of the confusion.

Comment: can we call $T$ as  operator?

Comment: If $T:V\to V$ then the dimension of the domain is the dimension of the image and $T$ is a square matrix.  $T:V\to W$ is more general, and $T$ may be of any shape.

Answer (score 4):

The notation $f : A \to B$ means that $f$ is a function from a set $A$ to a set $B$. Informally, $f$ rule that takes every point in $A$ to a point in $B$.

There is no requirement on $A$ and $B$, other than that they be sets. They don't have to be, for example, vector spaces. There may be no addition or scalar multiplication operations at all on $A$ and $B$.

So, if we say $T : V \to W$, despite choosing to use some suggestive letters like $T$, $V$, and $W$, all we are saying is that $V$ and $W$ are (completely unstructured) sets, and $T$ is some (possibly weird and wacky) function between them. The same can be said about $T : V \to V$, except $T$ is a rule that takes points in $V$ to other points in $V$, instead of $W$. There is no more information than that.

However, if we understand $V$ and $W$ to both be *vector spaces* over the same field $F$ (often $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$), then we can talk about very special types of functions: linear functions. These are often called "linear transformations", "linear maps", or in the case where $T : V \to V$, "linear operators". Such functions must satisfy the conditions
\begin{align*}
T(u + v) &= T(u) + T(v) \\
T(av) &= aT(v)
\end{align*}
for all $u, v \in V$ and $a \in F$.

The notation $T : V \to W$ does **not** automatically suggest that $T$ is linear. It is very possible to have a non-linear function $T$, but still denote it $T : V \to W$.

For example, consider the function $T : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^3$ defined by
$$T(x, y) = (0, x^2, y).$$
Note that it is a rule, taking each point in $\Bbb{R}^2$ to a point in $\Bbb{R}^3$. However, it is not linear, as
$$T(2(1, 0)) = T(2, 0) = (0, 4, 0),$$
but
$$2T(1, 0) = 2(0, 1, 0) = (0, 2, 0),$$
hence $T(av) = aT(v)$ is violated in the particular case $a = 2$ and $v = (1, 0)$.